# Submit People Picker value into Sharepoint list column(Person and group) in SPFX (No Javascript) framework

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx, spfx-webparts, people-picker, clientpeoplepicker

**Using SPClientPeoplePicker in the form**
**Is there any way to submit value from PeoplePicker into Sharepoint List Column(Person and group)**
**I am getting an error , using this piece of code for peoplepicker in the vs code only (Cannot find name 'SPClientPeoplePicker')**

**Below is the screenshot of my code**
[image]

**Pushing that peoplepicker user's key into an array for submission into sharepoint list column (person and group)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you loaded all the js files(the order also matters) which are required to create and read the people picker values

- clienttemplates.js
- clientforms.js
- clientpeoplepicker.js
- autofill.js
- sp.js
- sp.runtime.js
- sp.core.js

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/use-the-client-side-people-picker-control-in-sharepoint-hosted-sharepoint-add-in

please follow the https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/18424414-ee7d-4500-8c16-9ea152145d5a/how-to-create-a-people-picker-field-in-webpart-using-spfx-no-javascript-framework?forum=SP2019

Comment: Is there any way to use pnp-peoplepicker control in No javascript framework??